# Is retrofit of any use if I am already using okhttp3, Moshi and Rxjava in my project?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp, moshi

I have done some R&D on above libraries and have used some in my project.I am using Moshi for json parsing, OkHttp3 library for http connections and Rxjava for asynchronous and event based programming in my project. Now when I looked at retrofit, I felt its of no use as I have already used above main components of retrofit myself.
Just want to know the ideas of the people whether I am thinking in right direction or not.

**Edit:** From my point of view, Retrofit only provides clean interface of http client where one can customize requests,headers etc with annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good choice of libraries from my point of view. The first three are developed by Square and they work very well together. However the main difference is that each library works on a different layer.

OkHttp: transport layer. Deals with http protocol. Performs networking.

Moshi: Json parser. Transforms bytes from OkHttp into a Java objects.

Retrofit: Rest layer. Transforms HTTP logic (status codes), into REST logic.

RxJava: provides tools to create reactive code, instead of imperative code.